# Can i deploy a non maven java web application on heroku server if yes then how?

Tags: heroku

I have created war file of my non maven java web application. I am unknown to deploy this app on Heroku. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
heroku war:deploy war file location --app appName;"

if this show error as follows
ERROR: Your buildpacks do not contain the heroku/jvm buildpack!Add heroku/jvm to your buildpack configuration or run `heroku buildpacks:clear
then run the following command 
heroku buildpacks:clear --app APP
and again run 
heroku war:deploy war file location --app appName;"
```

you war file will be successfully depoyed.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Create Heroku account and follow Deploy section documentation.
But I'll flag down the question due to be too generic and non googled first.

Comment: i did google but i didn't understand the exact scenario.

Comment: A lot of things to start there before: start with account, dedicated web server for your war there and then you can just copy your war and run

Comment: please, provide more details on your specific issue then